# Blazor Server App HttpClient and TCPClient slow first time around when deployed on IIS

Tags: asp.net-core, iis, blazor, httpclient

I have an Blazor Server app target framework .NET 7.
The app calls a TCP server on load and subsequently makes some HTTPClient calls when buttons are pressed.
The app works perfectly and instantly when run through Visual Studio.

Although once deployed on IIS the TCP call at page load (OnInitializedAsync) takes 3 seconds and the first HTTPClient call when a button is pressed also takes 3 seconds.
The subsequent HTTPClient calls work instantly as a button is pressed. Make me think the first time around they needs loaded somehow.

Is there any setting that has to changed on the app or on the IIS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The client calls are made to the same machine but to different ports than the website.
When deployed in IIS I was using 'localhost' as base address.
For some reason changing to '127.0.0.1' made everything work instantly again.

Perhaps resolving localhost require much longer time.

Comment: If you can mark your answer, it will lead more people in the right direction.